# Can a USB pen drive have sector size > 512 bytes?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, sectors

Hard-disks, these days, can have sectors sized from 512 to 4096 bytes.

I would like to know if the same is also possible with USB removable storage media (flash drives, or pen drives).

Context: I need to test my code with a *real* (or, a *physical*) device having a sector-size > 512 bytes. It turns out that every USB device that I can get my hands on has a sector size of 512 bytes!

If you know of such a device (with sectors > 512 bytes), please share its make and model.

Comment: CD-ROMs have 2Kbyte sectors.

Comment: Get a 4k SSD and put it in a USB dock?

Comment: But won't it be seen as a non-removable HDD? Windows (and may be other OSes too) make a distinction between 'Removable Media' (such as flash drives) and USB-based external HDDs.